# "Values not normally distributed, so were transformed to log10 values before" - how to read the results?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution, arithmetic

I have been researching a medical topic and stumbled upon a paper that is really useful for me but I am limited by my math/statistics knowledge.

The paper reads as follows:

> the Gmax and Tlag measurements were not normally distributed and so
> were transformed to log10 values before t test analysis.

I have then the results:

Tlag (log 10)   0.19 for controls, 0.6 for disease group 1 and 0.9 for disease group 3.

How should I read that? For controls, the typical time lag is about 2-3 minutes but I cannot see how it correlates with the value 0.19.

I would be really grateful for help

Comment: The 10-logarithm of x is the value to which you must raise 10 to get x, so if $\log_{10} x = 0.19$ you have $x = 10^{0.19} \approx 1.55$.

Answer (score 0):

As @einar pointed out, to reverse the log10 transform, take 10 to that power. When you do this reverse transform for the mean of the logarithms, your result is the geometric mean of the values.

Ideally, compute the 95% confidence interval for the mean of the logarithms in the three groups, and transform the mean and both limits of the CI so you can express your results as the geometric mean with its 95% confidence interval.